# how can disable capture internal audio from my app ? ( Kotlin )

Tags: kotlin, audio, audio-recording, audio-capture

i want to prevent audio recording from my app ,
and i think disable capture internal audio will help ,
but i don't now how ?

i tried to detect State of AudioRecord ,
but it does not work with Android 10+